# a template pattern variant problem

Tags: c#, design-patterns

the implementer class 'thefoo' takes an integer from its constructor. but the base class 'foo' can not see its constructor value 'input'. because the base ctor works first. i'm need of some way to tell the base that implementer's ctor value. without changing the base can i make passed the following failingtest?

```
public abstract class foo
    {
        int noImplementerKnowsThatValue = 0;
        protected abstract int intro();
        protected abstract int outtro();

        public foo()
        {
            noImplementerKnowsThatValue += intro ();
        }

        public int compose ()
        {
            return noImplementerKnowsThatValue + outtro ();
        }
    }
    public class theFoo : foo
    {
        int value;

        public theFoo (int input)
        {
            value = input;
        }

        protected override int intro ()
        {
            return value;
        }

        protected override int outtro ()
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }

    public class fooTest
    {
        public void failingTest ()
        {
            var foo = new theFoo (100);
            int x = foo.compose ();
            Debug.Assert (200 == x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have the 'value' member defined in both classes? It's only necessary in the base class. Just make sure that it's defined as a protected member.

Comment: i think base class is not clear. i edited again.

Comment: Doesn't this assertion already pass? Or am I missing something?

Comment: nope and that's the problem. the constructor execution order. foo overrides theFoo's behavior. the reverse is acceptable but this one is so strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Not unless you change the base class.

Well, I suppose you could make

```
protected override int intro ()
{
    return 0;
}
protected override int outtro ()
{
    return 100 + value;
}
```

But I think that's not what you mean. And it doesn't solve the general case of this problem (for instance, if instead of `int` there would be `string`).

Comment: or if i use a referenced class in 'theFoo'

class Baz { public int value = 100;} 

 public class theFoo : foo
    {
        int value;

        public theFoo (Baz input)
        {
            value = input.Value;
        }
}
throws NullException because of the same problem

Comment: @jacklondon - exactly. Which is why it is highly discouraged to call virtual functions in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

if you can change `noImplementerKnowsThatValue` in base class to protected, you can do

```
public theFoo (int input)
{
    base.noImplementerKnowsThatValue = input;
    value = input;
}
```

I don't think there is a way to do this without changing the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious (making outtro return value + 100, instead of just 100), I cannot see any other mechanism that does not require changing the base class.